# Update page content via AJAX and update/ change URL

Tags: jquery, django

The main problem I am faced with is updating the URL of a page after a successful AJAX request. I use the $.ajax() method to empty contents of the current page then load the page the user wants to go to via the AJAX call. This goes well except that the URL does not change. I want it to behave like twitter somehow...

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use Ajax at all if you want the URL to change. The main point of using Ajax is to update part of the page without refreshing or changing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), but since it's a new technology, some browsers like IE9 and below do not support the API, if you want to support browsers that do not support the API you can consider using [`history.js`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js).

> History.js gracefully supports the HTML5 History/State APIs (pushState, replaceState, onPopState) in all browsers. Including continued support for data, titles, replaceState. Supports jQuery, MooTools and Prototype. For HTML5 browsers this means that you can modify the URL directly, without needing to use hashes anymore.